# Ever need to parse the svn log for files committed by a particular user since a certain date?

Tags: svn, awk, logging

If so the following one-liner utilizing awk might provide a useful template

```
svn log -v -r{2009-05-21}:HEAD | awk '/^r[0-9]+ / {user=$3} /yms_web/ {if (user=="george") {print $2}}' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add this to the list of [useful command-line svn examples](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/tagged/35/svn/sort-by-votes).

Answer (score 2):

Or use the XML output (--xml) of svn log and an Xslt processor.

Comment: That is a real good idea. I'm going to combine the question above, and the xml parsing to improve a powershell script I wrote.